# About Ubuntu One and re-check

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have a question, is there a way to tell Ubuntu One to compare and re-check the server and Pc synced files and folders to detect any diference between them?

Thanks for answering.-

Answer (score 2):

A resync should occur when the Ubuntu One client reconnects to the service.

You can force this by opening the `Ubuntu One` control panel, and clicking the `Disconnect` button in the top right, and then clicking the button again (it should now have the label `Connect`).

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to uncheck the synced folder from syncing and then recheck it again in the Ubuntu One window. On rechecking, the sync process is started again.

[image]

FYI: the method of disconnect and connect again, did not work for me, so I tried something else.